# Python Social Auth: How to define a different username scheme?

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

The default username-generation scheme in Python Social Auth is to take the username of the auth'd social network, and if it is already taken, add some sorta random value to it (or is it a hash?).

Anyway, I want to change that behavior, I want to define my own username-generation method. Like for example username+provider+random.

Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need is to replace `social.pipeline.user.get_username` from SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE with path to your own function returning generated username.

For example:

*project/myapp/settings.py*

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'project.myapp.utils.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

*project/myapp/utils.py:*

```
from social.pipeline.user import get_username as social_get_username
from random import randrange

def get_username(strategy, details, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    result = social_get_username(strategy, details, user=user, *args, **kwargs)
    result['username'] = '-'.join([
        result['username'], strategy.backend.name, str(randrange(0, 1000))
    ])
    return result
```

In above function I'm calling default `get_username` method from `python-social-auth` module and to result append provider name and random number between 0 and 1000.

**You can check source code of [social.pipeline.user.get_username on GitHub](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/pipeline/user.py#L9-L53)**.

Comment: There was a problem with randrange there, an exception: exception
sequence item 2: expected string or Unicode, int found

, but I fixed it and now it works, I can fully control username generation. Nice.

Comment: Ahh, my mistake, I forget to convert int into str. Code updated.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks it helped me a lot !!